# Stop neo4j jdbc printing the queries to console

Tags: java, jdbc, neo4j

I am using [neo4j-jdbc](https://github.com/rickardoberg/neo4j-jdbc) and my console output get full from messages like

```
Executing query: MATCH (n1:User {user_id:37935971})MATCH (n2:User {user_id:55289537})MATCH (n1)-[r]->(n2)SET r.timestamp = 1400507999000 with params {}
```

and

```
Unexpected token END_ARRAY
errors-next-token = FIELD_NAME
null
```

As far as i know the second one is a bug and doesn't mean anything. However, is there a way to stop neo4j-jdbc printing this messages to my output?

Comment: It's a leftover and will be fixed with the next release.

Comment: Is there any temporal solution? When is the next release scheduled?

Answer (score 1):

The code that [prints this message](https://github.com/rickardoberg/neo4j-jdbc/blob/f5a1093a2d241cae91e6d88c92bb827893fa307d/src/main/java/org/neo4j/jdbc/Neo4jConnection.java) uses [Apache Commons Logging](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/), which is a thin wrapper over over logging libraries.   Their software dependencies indicate that the specific logging library they use is called [logback](http://logback.qos.ch/).

So to silence these messages, you must configure the logging library to shut up.  Logging libraries have different "levels" so that a message could be just "info", "severe", "warning", and so on.  The message you're seeing is an "info" message.   So if you configure the log library not to display those, it won't.

[Here's the documentation on how to do that configuration.](https://wiki.base22.com/display/btg/How+to+setup+SLF4J+and+LOGBack+in+a+web+app+-+fast)